# Incorrect output for sentence_transformers CrossEncoder

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

I am looking at the following example from the huggingface website (https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/cross-encoder/README.html)

```
from sentence_transformers.cross_encoder import CrossEncoder

model = CrossEncoder(‘bert_base_uncased')

scores = model.predict([["My first", "sentence pair"], 

                    ["Second text", "pair"]])
```

When I run this code it outputs the following.
[image]

But on the website it says the following.
“ In contrast, for a Cross-Encoder, we pass both sentences simultaneously to the Transformer network. It produces than an output value between 0 and 1 indicating the similarity of the input sentence pair:”

It seems as though each sentence pair is actually getting two values. Can someone explain what each of these means or why it doesn’t seem to line up with the expected output?